# change open graph title in yoast plugin using a function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

im not en experienced coder but here we go....im using yoast seo which add the open graph metas. When i share a woocommerce product over whatsapp for example is not passing the product price...so im attempting to add the price just after the title....of course is not working :-(

```
function change_yoast_seo_og_meta() {

   add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'change_title' );

}

function change_title( $title ) {

echo $sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true);


$regular_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);


if ($regular_price == ""){

$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id']; 

$variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

$regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
}

   $title = __( $regular_price, 'change_textdomain' );

  return $title;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Thanx! I put the code at the end of the functions.php and is not modifying the og:title when i check in the source code of the page, there is not errors.